# Why is the triangle inequality in a weighted graph always satisfied? Why is this not a counter-example?

Tags: graph-theory, triangle-inequality

I am wanting to know why the triangle inequality is always satisfied in a weighted graph. In particular, I want to know why the attached graph (please click the link weighted K_5 below) is not a counter-example. Is it true that the triangle inequality says that for any vertices $u, v, w \in V(G)$, $wt(u,v) < wt(u,w) + wt(w,v)$? Because in the graph, if we consider $u=v_3, v=v_4$ and $w=v_2$, we have that $wt(v_3, v_4)=8, wt(v_3, v_2)=4$ and $wt(v_2, v_4)=2$. In this case $wt(v_3, v_4) \nless wt(v_3, v_2) + wt(v_2, v_4)$, which is $8 \nless 4+2$.
I know I am wrong, no doubt, I'm just struggling to see why.

I want to clarify this because I want to see which graphs cannot be used to solve the Travelling Salesman problem (TSP).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Weighted K_5:
[image: weighted K_5]

Comment: Depends on if the graph came from the real world, and if weights measure distances. Real (planar, euclidean) triangles do satisfy the triangle-inequality, so if the problem came from the real world, you can most likely use this assumption (unless the area is extremely hilly). However obviously you can write up a theoretical graph that does satisfy the triangle inequality. Looks like the graph shown in the image is one of these examples, because of has the (8,4,2) triangle you mentioned, so it must not have come from real world (planar) distances.

Comment: the triangle inequality for *weights* is not always satisfied since weights can be anything.  the triangle inequality for *distances* is always true.

Comment: Why "Distance" will always have the triangle relation while "Weight" may not ? Think about this : In your graph , let each Vertex represent a City & let the Distance (or time Equivalent) be the Weight on each Edge between 2 Cities. Now , you can arbitrarily make a Weight 0 or even negative ! We can not conclude that there is no triangle relation , Eg going from A to B will take 0 time & going from C to D will take negative time ! When we use real Distances & times , we will Definitely have the triangle relation ! Check with Points on Euclidean Plane.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your responses. 
However, I am still a bit confused as this complete graph, in particular, was used in a university textbook as an example of how to solve the travelling salesman problem (TSP). The TSP is only defined when the graph satisfies the triangle inequality, so I was under the assumption that this graph did satisfy the triangle inequality. I have seen many examples where this is the case. Have I got the definition correct of the triangle inequality with weights?

Comment: *I have just double-checked and the textbook says that this graph DOES satisfy the triangle inequality, so I want to know why my observation is incorrect. Is the triangle inequality for weighted graphs still defined for distances, irrespective of the weights? If so, what is an example of a graph that does not satisfy the triangle inequality?

Comment: "The TSP is only defined when the graph satisfies the triangle inequality" - why do you say this? You can solve the traveling salesman problem for any weighted graph, though the metric TSP (where we restrict to graphs that satisfy the triangle inequality) is easier to solve approximately. Anyway, if the textbook says that this graph satisfies the triangle inequality, it's just wrong.

Comment: What is the textbook?

Comment: The weight of a *path* is the sum of the weights of its edges. The *distance* between two nodes is the smallest weight of a *path* between them. With these definitions, the triangle equality for distances is obvious. $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ because $d(x,z)$ considers paths that go through $y$.